# convert DevExpress.Xpo.XPCollection`1 to DevExpress.Xpo.XPCollection

Tags: c#, collections, devexpress

Hello I need to get two collections as XpCollections, but "cMemberInfo.GetValue(this)" brings me type "DevExpress.Xpo.XPCollection`1" is it possible to convert it in some way to the
DevExpress.Xpo.XPCollection?

```
                XPCollection cColl1 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(this) as XPCollection;
            XPCollection cColl2 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(cObject) as XPCollection;
```

As the result of not converting type both cColl are null

there is full part of code where these collections are used

```
            foreach (XPMemberInfo cMemberInfo in ClassInfo.CollectionProperties)
        {
            XPCollection cColl1 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(this) as XPCollection;

            XPCollection cColl2 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(cObject) as XPCollection;

            if (cColl1 == null || cColl2 == null) { Debug.Assert(false); return false; }
            if (cColl1.Count != cColl2.Count) { return false; }

            for (int i = 0; i < cColl1.Count; ++i)
            {
                XPOBase cObj1 = cColl1[i] as XPOBase;
                XPOBase cObj2 = cColl2[i] as XPOBase;

                bRet &= cObj1.IsDataEqual(cObj2);
            }
        }
```

if I use XPBaseCollection in case of XPCollection I cannot declare cColl1[i] or cColl2[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetValue is returning a generic `XPCollection<T>` where T is the type of the objects of the collection.

```
XPCollection<MyType> cColl1 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(this) as XPBaseCollection<MyType>;
XPCollection<MyOtherType> cColl2 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(cObject) as XPBaseCollection<MyOtherType>;
```

Or you could use `XPBaseCollection` instead:

```
XPBaseCollection cColl1 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(this) as XPBaseCollection;
XPBaseCollection cColl2 = cMemberInfo.GetValue(cObject) as XPBaseCollection;
```

Comment: CI thought about type, but this method is used with different types.
I'll try with XPBaseCollection, no does not suits.
I edited my post added more code.

Comment: @konopiuxkonopiux you can use [XPBaseCollection.BaseIndexer](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoXPBaseCollection_BaseIndexertopic) method to fetch collection objects.